# Scala boolean always returning false

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

I was wondering why the following function `doesMsgExist()` always returns `false` even when the results from the DB is not empty.

```
def doesMsgExist(name: String, age: String): Boolean = {
    var result = false
    val msgExistsFlag = checkExistingMessages(db.getDocument(name, age))
    msgExistsFlag.foreach(isTrue => result = if(isTrue) false else true)
    result
  }


  def checkExistingMessages(resultFromDB: Future[List[BSONDocument]]): Future[Boolean] = {

    resultFromDB.map { list =>

      if (list.isEmpty) {
        false
      }
      else true
    }

  }
```

Comment: I think this question has a too wide scope, please consider restricting the scope of the question, like leaving only the `checkExistingMessages` method and letting us know how it behaves with different input.

Comment: I don't see how it could have too wide a scope. Seems fairly straight forward what is being asked and to what the underlying issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are immediately returning the `result` but you are using a `Future` to evaluate it. That means that the object which represents the computation is being created but you have no guarantee *when* that computation will resolve. Hence, the value you return is `false`.

Think of a `Future` as a place holder for some action which will happen in the future. If you want to capture the actual result you should do something with a signature like this:

```
def doesMsgExist(name: String, age: Boolean): Future[Boolean] =
```

and have the evaluation returned with the `Future`. If not, you're going to have to surround it by an `Await`.

Comment: Is there anything else other than setting a time limit? Why does it have to be so complex, all I want is to see the result of a DB operation.

Comment: @summerNight it's "complex" being you've introduced multi-threading. There is no other way.